# ionic: ion-list above google map with animation

Tags: cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework

Iam a beginner in ionic. I have a requirement which have ion-list above map view.[image: Image example]

I don't know how to achieve this design. Below google map view, The list of one item has displayed. when we scroll up the list will occupy 90% of the screen. Again we can scroll down the view list.

Please can someone suggest me that how can i approach this scenario with animation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?
"map_canvas" div is Google maps container

```css
.events-map-container {
    height: 90%;
}

.events-list-container {
    height: 10%;
}
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>My Route</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div id="map_canvas" class="events-map-container"></div>
  <div class="event-list-container"></div>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-icon name="leaf" item-start></ion-icon>
      <h2>Bachelor party</h2>
      <p>21/01/2018</p>
      <ion-icon name="information-circle" item-end></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-icon name="leaf" item-start></ion-icon>
      <h2>Bachelor party</h2>
      <p>21/01/2018</p>
      <ion-icon name="information-circle" item-end></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-icon name="leaf" item-start></ion-icon>
      <h2>Bachelor party</h2>
      <p>21/01/2018</p>
      <ion-icon name="information-circle" item-end></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-icon name="leaf" item-start></ion-icon>
      <h2>Bachelor party</h2>
      <p>21/01/2018</p>
      <ion-icon name="information-circle" item-end></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-icon name="leaf" item-start></ion-icon>
      <h2>Bachelor party</h2>
      <p>21/01/2018</p>
      <ion-icon name="information-circle" item-end></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-icon name="leaf" item-start></ion-icon>
      <h2>Bachelor party</h2>
      <p>21/01/2018</p>
      <ion-icon name="information-circle" item-end></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-icon name="leaf" item-start></ion-icon>
      <h2>Bachelor party</h2>
      <p>21/01/2018</p>
      <ion-icon name="information-circle" item-end></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-icon name="leaf" item-start></ion-icon>
      <h2>Bachelor party</h2>
      <p>21/01/2018</p>
      <ion-icon name="information-circle" item-end></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```